# HttpClient: Correct order to detect encoding

Tags: c#, http, encoding, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using HttpClient to fetch some files. I put the content into a byte array (bytes). Now I need to detect the encoding. The contenttype will be either html, css, JavaScript or XML contenttype.

Currently I check the charset from headers, then check for a BOM (byte order mark) before I finally check the first part of the file for a charset meta tag.
Normally this works fine, because there are no conflicts.

**But: Is that order correct (in case of conflict)?**

The code I corrently use:

```js
Encoding encoding;
try
{
    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet);
}
catch
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.Default, true))
        {
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            sr.Read(chars, 0, 1024);
            string textDefault = new string(chars);
            if (sr.CurrentEncoding == Encoding.Default)
            {
                encoding = Global.EncodingFraContentType(textDefault);
            }
            else
            {
                encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding;
            }
        }
    }
}
responseInfo.Text = encoding.GetString(bytes);
```

Global.EncodingFraContentType is a regular expression that finds the charset defined either in XML declaration, or in a meta tag.

**What order is the correct to detect charset/encoding?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conclusion** - in order of importance:

1. **Byte Order Mark (BOM)**: If present, this is **AUTHORATIVE**, since it was
   added by the editor that actually saved the file (this can only be
   present on `unicode` encodings).
2. **Content-Type charset** (in header set by the server): For dynamically created/processed files, it should be present (since the
   server knows), but might not be for static files (the server just
   sends those).
3. **Inline charset**: For xml, html and css the encoding can be be specified inside the document, in either `xml prolog`, `html meta tag`
   or `@charset in css`.  To read that you need to decode the first
   part of the document using for instance **'Windows-1252' encoding**.
4. **Assume utf-8**. This is the `standard of the web` and is today by far the most used.
5. If the found encoding equals '`ISO-8859-1`', use '`Windows-1252`' instead (required in html5 - read more at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

Now **try to decode** the document using the found encoding. If `error handling` is turned on, that might fail! In that case:

6. **Use 'Windows-1252'**. This was the standard in old windows files and works fine as last try (there's still a lot of old files out there).
   This will `never throw` errors. However it might of course be wrong.

I have made a method that implements this. The `regex` I use is able to find encodings specified as:

**Xml**: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` OR `<?xml encoding="utf-8"?>`

**html**: `<meta charset="utf-8" />` OR `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

**css**: `@charset "utf-8"`;

(It works with both single and double qoutes).

You will need:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Here's the method that returns the decoded string (parameters are the `HttpClient` and the `Uri`):

```
public static async Task<string> GetString(HttpClient httpClient, Uri url)
{
    byte[] bytes;
    Encoding encoding = null;
    Regex charsetRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=(<meta.*?charset=|^\<\?xml.*?encoding=|^@charset[ ]?)[""']?)[\w-]+?(?=[""';\r\n])",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

    using (HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        bytes = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        string headerCharset = responseMessage?.Content?.Headers?.ContentType?.CharSet;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
        Array.Copy(bytes, buffer, Math.Min(bytes.Length, buffer.Length));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"), true, buffer.Length, true))
            {
                string testString = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (!sr.CurrentEncoding.Equals(Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")))
                {
                    encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding;
                }
                else if (headerCharset != null)
                {
                    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(headerCharset, EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback);
                }
                else
                {
                    string inlineCharset = charsetRegex.Match(testString).Value;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inlineCharset))
                    {
                        encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(inlineCharset, EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
                    }
                }
                if (encoding.Equals(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
                {
                    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252", EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback);
                }
            }
        }
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, encoding, false, 0x8000, true))
                {
                    return await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            catch (DecoderFallbackException)
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"), false, 0x8000, true))
                {
                    return await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should wrap the method call in a try/catch, since `HttpClient` can throw errors, if the request fails.

**Update**:

In `.Net Core`, you don't have the 'Windows-1252' encoding (big mistake IMHO), so here you must settle with '`ISO-8859-1`'.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer depends not on order, but on which actually gives the correct result, and there's no perfect answer here.

If there is a conflict, then the server has given you something incorrect. Since it's incorrect there can't be a "correct" order because there isn't a correct way of being incorrect. And, maybe the header and the embedded metadata are both wrong!

No even slightly common-used encoding can have something that looks like a BOM would look like in UTF-8 or UTF-16 at the beginning and still be a valid example of the content types you mention, so if there's a BOM then that wins.

(The one exception to that is if the document is so badly edited as to switch encoding part-way through, which is no unheard of, but then the buggy content is so very buggy as to have no real meaning).

If the content contains no octet that is greater than 0x7F then it doesn't matter and the header and metadata both claim it as different examples of US-ASCII, UTF-8, any of the ISO-8859 family of encodings, or any of the other encodings for which those octets all map to the same code point, then it doesn't really matter which you consider it to be, as the nett result is the same. Consider it to be whatever the metadata says, as then you don't need to rewrite it to match correctly.

If it's in UTF-16 without a BOM it is likely going to be clearly as such very soon as all of those formats have a lot of characters with special meaning in the range U+0000 to U+00FF (indeed, generally U+0020 to U+007F) and so you'll have lots of ranges with a zero byte every other character.

If it has octets above 0x7F and is valid UTF-8, then it's almost certainly UTF-8. (By the same token if it's not UTF-8 and has octets above 0x7F then it almost certainly can't be mistaken for UTF-8).

The trickiest reasonably common case is if you have conflicting claims about it being in two different encodings which are both single-octet-per-character encodings and an octet in the range 0x80-0xFF is present. This is the case that you can't be sure about. If one encoding is a subset of the other (especially when C1 controls are excluded) then you could go for the superset, but that requires storing knowledge about those encodings, and considerable amount of work. Most of the time I'd be inclined to just throw an exception, and when it's found in the logs see if I can get the source to fix their bug, or special-case that source, but that doesn't work if you are dealing with a very large number of disparate sources that you may not have a relationship with. Alas there is no perfect answer here.

Its worth noting also that sometimes both header and embedded metadata will agree with each other incorrectly. A common case is content in CP-1252 but claimed as being in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 2):

According to [W3C Faq](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en)

> If you have a UTF-8 byte-order mark (BOM) at the start of your file then recent browser versions other than Internet Explorer 10 or 11 will use that to determine that the encoding of your page is UTF-8. It has a higher precedence than any other declaration, including the HTTP header.

When it comes to the http-header vs meta BOM takes precedence, as long as the meta is within the first 1024 it can take precedence, though there is no strict rule on that.

Comment: Your answer looks a bit messed up. A sentence is started but not ended. Some unquoted parts seem to come from linked page.

Comment: @Frédéric - Thanks for the feedback - Less is more, amended accordingly