# C# httpclient unicode characters in response body

Tags: c#, unicode, httpclient

When requesting with the httpclient, sometimes there are unknown characters (��ٓ�����) in the response body.

my try

```
static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new();
public static async Task<DSModel> GetRequestAsync()
{
string host="https://www.example.com/";

using var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri(host),
    Content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")

};

request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
//request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
//request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");

try
{
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        string jsonResponse = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        return jsonResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        // Http Status Code !200
    }
}
catch
{
    //try catch error
}
}
```

this is my test links for requests

https:// [removed].co.jp/

https:// www.[removed].com/

The first link works correctly, but the second link has unintelligible characters (�)

I added utf-8 to the request header

I also tried the response with Html Decode

**Update**

My problem was due to charset and I found the right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61775060/3988509)

So my code will be like this

```
static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new();
public static async Task<DSModel> GetRequestAsync(string url)
{

request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

try
{
using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
string headerCharset = response?.Content?.Headers?.ContentType?.CharSet;

byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
Array.Copy(bytes, buffer, Math.Min(bytes.Length, buffer.Length));
using (MemoryStream ms = new (buffer))
{
    using StreamReader sr = new(ms, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"), true, buffer.Length, true);
    string testString = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (!sr.CurrentEncoding.Equals(Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")))
    {
        encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding;
    }
    else if (headerCharset != null)
    {
        encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(headerCharset, EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback);
    }
    else
    {
        string inlineCharset = charsetRegex.Match(testString).Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inlineCharset))
        {
            encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(inlineCharset, EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback);
        }
        else
        {
            encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
        }
    }

    if (encoding.Equals(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
    {
        encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252", EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback);
    }
}

using (MemoryStream ms = new (bytes))
{
    string Response;
    try
    {
        using StreamReader sr = new(ms, encoding, false, 0x8000, true);
        Response = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (DecoderFallbackException)
    {
        ms.Position = 0;
        using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"), false, 0x8000, true);
        Response = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return Response = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Response);
}
}
else
{
    // Http Status Code !200
}
}
catch
{
    //try catch error
}
```

Comment: `utf-8` is the correct content type for the first one.  The second one looks to be `euc-jp` from the meta tags in the response.  Check out https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/779 for more details.